# SQL Server 2008R2 Agent Malware

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs, job-scheduling

List of unidentified sql jobs

[image: List of unidentified sql jobs]

Our SQL Server 2008 R2 has lots of auto generated jobs from nowhere as can be seen from image above. I strongly suspect this causes our server password keeps reset daily for no reasons (I had untick those 'Enforce password policy' checkboxes). For now I had delete the jobs but I am not sure can this really solve the root of the problems. Any idea on this? Thanks guys...

Comment: It seems your SQL Server has been compromised. Perhaps it is exposed to the public internet without proper firewall rules and security measures in place. Why did you turn off enforce password policy?

Comment: I don't see any evidence that these jobs were maliciously created or "auto generated". Unless of course you are the only person that creates jobs, and you did not create these. They certainly look nasty. Perhaps you should crack one open and see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Your server has most likely been compromised. The most appropriate thing to do in this situation is to either reinstall everything from scratch and restore your last known good data backup (prior to getting compromised), or perform a bare metal restore of the server from the last known good (uncompromised) backup. At this point you don't know what malicious software is still on that server, so you have to assume that it's riddled with it.

Do this *after* you've ensured that the server will be secured from network attacks and don't leave it exposed to the public internet. If it wasn't previously exposed, you may have malicious software on your company network.